# How to fix networking after installing a new CPU/Motherboard?

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, lan, wired

Upgraded from an AthlonII to an FX-8350. This meant new motherboard/integrated LAN. I can't figure out how to configure the new setup to connect to my network. Any help appreciated. Also, as i obviously don't have internet, it's going to be a little tough to get new isntalls onto it. I'm not entirely familiar with mounting flash drives. There is no CD drive.

Edit #1:

Now using a GA-990FXA-UD3 Motherboard. It has a Realtek Ethernet, from what I can find. I don't know which chip exactly.

```
lspci | grep -i eth

04.00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express  Gigabet Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

Comment: Start by checking /var/log/syslog and check if the interface has the same name. also have a look at dmesg. Things like `udev[nnn]: renamed network interface ethN to ethX` are important. And `supplicant_interface_acquire` Also: you might need to add a kernel module for your interface.

Comment: First step, tell us what make/model the motherboard is. Even better, find out what chip the network port uses. From there we need to figure out if the Linux kernel supports it (likely should), and if you'll need to install anything.