# Network connections not working after new motherboard installation (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, motherboard

So I installed a new motherboard with an existing Ubuntu install and now my network won't connect (wired).

The first help thread I read suggested deleting `/etc/udev/70-persistent-net.rules` and then rebooting, saying that this file would get recreated on startup.  I tried this and rebooted several times but no replacement file is created.

Other recommendations include changing the `eth0` string in `/etc/udev/70-persistent-net.rules` to the new `eth`, but they don't say where I can see what the new `eth` # is for the new motherboard.

I've tried ifconfig and noticed the inet6 addr doesn't look like a full address.  Not sure if this is a problem.

```
lo
Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK running MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:1520 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
RX packets:1520 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:119430 (119.4KB) TX bytes:119430 (119.4 KB)
```

New motherboard is a Gigabyte Z170XP-SLI, if that matters.

As per [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270582/how-to-fix-networking-after-installing-a-new-cpu-motherboard) I've checked `/var/log/syslog` but have found no `udev[nnn]: renamed network interface ethN to ethX` lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming all other components - I/O devices, microprocessor, disks, sound or graphics card remains the same and only Motherboard is changed. While installing Ubuntu many times on various machines - I have looked into the logs and there are lots of drivers in kernel as well as packages to support those devices. I will say it will be a good idea to have a backup of your data and then do a reinstall. Once you have a stable system you can get your data from backup storage. 
Fixing one problem after the other might take a lot of efforts in my opinion.

Comment: That's what I ended up having to do :(   

Sad that I couldn't figure it out but at least reinstalling isn't too difficult.